# Cordova for Android: HTML5 video tag plays video without image

Tags: android, html, cordova, video

I created a very new Cordova (6.4.0) project， placed a html5 video tag in the html body. Running the project for iOS, it works well. But for Android (6.0.0), the video plays without image UNTIL the zoom button in lower right corner is clicked.

[White screen when playing the video for Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHGu8.png)

Here is the html:

```
<body>
    <video controls="controls" src="http://url/somemovie.MOV"></video>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that your video doesn't auto-play until you click on something, you may be encountering a deliberate limitation Google inserted into their mobile Chrome browser, which stops videos from auto-playing without user interaction. The reasoning behind this is because on mobile devices, bandwidth may result in charges to the user. (Hopefully they'll change their minds in future.)

However, there is a workaround for this, where you can still auto-play a video as long as it is muted by using the autoplay and muted properties. Example:

```
<video autoplay loop muted poster="/app/img/videos/timeapps.jpg">
    <source src="/app/img/videos/timeapps.mp4" />
</video>
```

In the example above, I also have a poster image to display while the video content is first loaded.

Comment: Thank you anyway~ I just don't understand why the image doesn't show until it's on the full screen mode on android.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Set the video full screen mode when it's played for android.

```
if (_IsAndroid()){
    video = attElement.querySelector('.video');
    video.src = filepath;
    video.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    //video.onclick = function(){document.webkitExitFullscreen();}
}
```